# Where does Stripe Checkout send a charge token?

Tags: stripe-payments

If I setup Checkout on a website hosted on one server will the checkout token created when someone fills out a Checkout form be sent to Stripe and can therefore be pulled into any additional server which is integrated with Stripe.com via one of their client libraries and the secret or live key associated with a Stripe account? In other words, what is the process by which a charge token is sent?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the token gets posted to the action you list in the form that contains Stripe checkout, though you could also access it via a javascript token.

Tokens are only guaranteed for 5 minutes and only work with your secret API key. There is no api API endpoint to just list the tokens in your account so you would need to send it from the checkout form to the server of your choosing.